# Merge Sort JS .......Not able to understand it

Tags: javascript

```js
function MergeSortCaller() {
    let array = [7, 2, 9, 3]
    const auxiliaryArray = array.slice();
    partition (array, 0, array.length - 1, auxiliaryArray);
}

function partition(
    mainArray,
    startIdx,
    endIdx,
    auxiliaryArray,
) {
    if (startIdx === endIdx) return;
    const middleIdx = Math.floor((startIdx + endIdx) / 2);
    partition (auxiliaryArray, startIdx, middleIdx, mainArray);
    partition (auxiliaryArray, middleIdx + 1, endIdx, mainArray);
    doMerge (mainArray, startIdx, middleIdx, endIdx, auxiliaryArray);

}

function doMerge(
    mainArray,
    startIdx,
    middleIdx,
    endIdx,
    auxiliaryArray,
) {

    let k = startIdx;
    let i = startIdx;
    let j = middleIdx + 1;
    while (i <= middleIdx && j <= endIdx) {
        if (auxiliaryArray[i] <= auxiliaryArray[j]) {
            mainArray[k++] = auxiliaryArray[i++];
        } else {
            mainArray[k++] = auxiliaryArray[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i <= middleIdx) {
        mainArray[k++] = auxiliaryArray[i++];
    }
    while (j <= endIdx) {
        mainArray[k++] = auxiliaryArray[j++];
    }
    console.log(auxiliaryArray, mainArray)
}

MergeSortCaller()
```

Output:-

1. Aux  -> 7 2 9 3
   Main -> 2 7 9 3
2. Aux  -> 7 2 9 3
   Main -> 2 7 3 9
3. Aux  -> 2 7 3 9
   Main -> 2 3 7 9

This is working code of Merge Sort. But I am not able to get that how in the 3rd call of doMerge(), the auxilaryArray get changed even I don't make any change to it.
In the code all the changes are happening to mainArray.
PLZ help me...

Thanks...

Comment: ok, I have added some context . Plz watch it.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Visit [Graphical Structure](https://graphicalstructure.codes/Playground) for Visualization of mergesort it may help you.